# Asp .NET MVC Core application not running in Windows Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to deploy an asp.net core mvc application in the docker container, when i run the application i get the following error in the docker logs

> **fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZYCL.png)
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString**

I have mentioned the connection string in my appsettings.json file but still it does not fetch it correctly.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "<<< AZURE-SQL CONNECTION STRING >>>"
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

            services.AddScoped<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic>();
            services.AddScoped<IDataRepository, DataRepository>();

var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddScoped<DataContext>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Mvc}/{action=Design}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

**Published folder**

[image: Published folder]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
EXPOSE 80

COPY  /publish/ /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MVC_Module_Designer.dll"]
```

**Docker commands used to publish**

```
docker build -t webapp .

docker run -p 8080:80 webapp
```

> Am i missing out anything for deployment of asp.net mvc core application in docker container ?.

Comment: I believe your issue is `services.AddScoped<DataContext>();`. This is unnecessary as `AddDbContext<DataContext>` has already registered the service as scoped. You're essentially overriding that registration, with a context instance that hasn't been configured.

Comment: Does the same error occur when you run the application outside of docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue that i have made, its in the Docker file, after copying the published folder to app directory, did not change it to that. Hence it resulted in that error.

Correct docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app

COPY  /publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MVC_Module_Designer.dll"]
```